How to omit a wrapper message in the data class when (de)serializing?
I have a Protobuf message structure like this:
message TopLevel {
    required Identifier identifier = 1;
}

message Identifier {
    required uint64 value = 1;
}

Now, I want to use kotlinx.serialization to serialize this, but I also want to omit the "wrapper" message. Basically, I want to have a data class like this:
@Serializable
data class TopLevel(
    val identifier: Long
)

However, this (obviously) doesn't work straight away. I tried to write a custom serializer:
object IdentifierSerializer: KSerializer<Long> {
    override val descriptor: SerialDescriptor
        get() = buildClassSerialDescriptor("Identifier") {
            element<Long>("Value")
        }

    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): Long {
        return decoder.decodeStructure(descriptor) {
            decodeLongElement(descriptor, 0)
        }
    }

    override fun serializer(encoder: Encoder, value: Long) {
        encoder.encodeStructure(descriptor) {
            encodeLongElement(descriptor, 0, value)
        }
    }
}

And I also annotated the field with the serializer:
@Serializable
data class TopLevel(
    @Serializable(with = IdentifierSerializer::class)
    val identifier: Long
)

However, this throws an error when trying to deserialize:
Expected wire type VARINT(0), but found INVALID(-1)

What's causing this, and how could I resolve this?

Not a Kotlin developer so I don't know why your deserializer doesn't work but that seems like a reasonable approach. Alternatively, it is good practice to separate your application classes from the protobuf-generated classes and provide mappings between them. This gives you another degree of freedom and is potentially more readable.
